# Show rows from dataframe where column values (strings) are similar to input values (strings)

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe:

```
    column1
0   knight
1   chair
2   chicken
3   mango
```

Now I want to search for words in this dataframe that are similar to input letters I give the comupter. For example:

```
input = "a"

output= [chair, mango]
```

or

```
input = "kn"

output = [knight]
```

All I have tried so far is to check if the input and row values are identical. But I do not want them to be totally identical but instead similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **contains()**

this will mark a row that contain your string with true and the oposite with false :

```
data = df['column1'].str.contains('kn')
```

to get only the row that contain your strin use this :

```
df[df['column1'].str.contains('kn')]
```

Comment: is it possible to have something similar to the ,,contains" funtion which ignores capital letters?